# aws cli cp with = in prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to copy contents of s3 prefix recursively. The paths are

```
s3://a/b/c/d/dt=20230726/tm=0700/1.parquet
s3://a/b/c/d/dt=20230726/tm=0700/2.parquet
s3://a/b/c/d/dt=20230726/tm=0700/3.parquet
... and so on
```

The following command fails:

```
aws s3 cp s3://a/b/c/d/dt=20230726/tm=0700/ local_dir --recursive
```

Error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided check you key and signing method
```

[image]

Is there a way I can download these files?

Comment: I tried it on my Mac and it worked fine with objects that had an equals in the name. What happens if you try to copy a single file (`aws s3 cp s3://a/b/c/d/dt=20230726/tm=0700/1.parquet .`)? How about if you wrap it in quotes (`aws s3 cp 's3://a/b/c/d/dt=20230726/tm=0700/1.parquet' .`)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I attached the error message to my question for easy reference. Same error for single file or using quotes for the path.

Comment: Are you able to successfully download _any_ object from that bucket?

Comment: Only using browser download button. Could this be http proxy thing? I am trying to download on my local computer from s3.

Comment: It sounds like you might have incorrect credentials stored on your computer. Can you run `aws s3 ls`? If it generates the same error, then run `aws configure` and re-enter your credentials. The Access Key should start with `AKIA`.

Comment: I am logged in correctly. No issues with listing buckets using `aws s3 ls`

Comment: Can you upload a file from your computer to that bucket by using `aws s3 cp file.txt s3://bucket-name/`? Then, are you able to download it with `aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/file.txt .`? Then, repeat the exercise where there is an equals sign in the filename. The goal is to find what 'difference' is causing the command to file and whether it is related to 'all' objects, 'some' objects, a particular directory, etc. I should also ask whether you are downloading from your _own_ bucket or from somebody else's bucket?